# How to use sed to remove null bytes?

Tags: sed

What is the `sed` incantation to remove null bytes from a file?  I'm trying:

```
s/\000//g
```

but that is stripping out strings of zeroes.

```
s/\x00//g
```

seems to have no effect.  I'm trying to do this in a `sed` script, so I'm not sure the `echo` trick will work.

Answer (score 64):

I don't know how you can exactly achieve this with `sed`, but this is a solution that works with `tr`:

```
tr < file-with-nulls -d '\000' > file-without-nulls
```

This is a solution for `sed` that works with some (but not all) implementations of `sed`:

```
sed 's/\x0//g' file1 > file2
```

This is a solution that involves replacing into space characters which should work in all occasions:

```
sed 's/\x0/ /g' file1 > file2
```

Comment: that looks like a very incomplete answer. why would it work on some occasions and not others, and if so then wouldn't an example be useful?

Comment: @barlop: Because of the way it is implemented? The OP didn't specify one and I'm not going to enumerate every single implementation...

Comment: Well that then sounds fine to me, so you're saying it depends on the implementation of SED. If you hadn't said that you'd have left open the possible suggestion that one implementation of SED may remove nulls from one file and not another file, depending on the data in the file.

Comment: shouldn't it be "tr -d '\000' < file-with-nulls > file-without-nulls" ?

Comment: I needed to convert nul to newline, `sed 's/\x0/\n/g'` worked for me

Comment: Works for me™. Also useful: `-i` parameter to convert file in place.

Comment: `tr < file-with-nulls -d '\000' > file-without-nulls` works beautifully

Comment: According to the documentation for GNU sed, `\xxx` can be used to produce a character whose hexidecimal value is **`xx`**.  To produce `NULL`, use `\x00`.

Answer (score 9):

`tr` tripped over some other bytes in my file and `sed` didn't replace anything. I ended up doing it not in `sed` but in Python:

```
f = open('file-with-0bytes.dump')
for l in f.readlines():
  print l.replace("\0", '')
```

Here's a *pipeable* one-liner:

```
python -c 'import sys; sys.stdout.write(sys.stdin.read().replace("\0", ""))'
```

I also noticed some commands actually leave the null bytes there but they're not visible anymore, at least not in an OSX terminal. I used `hexdump` to debug this.

Answer (score 6):

It's quite easy to use Perl to perform a regex. Just replace `sed` with `perl -np -e`:

```
$ printf 'one\0two\0' | perl -np -e 's/\0/\n/g'
one
two
```

With the `-n` option, regexes are run line by line, just like sed.

If you want to use zero bytes as record separators, use Perl's `-0` option.

```
$ printf 'one\0two\0' | perl -np0 -e 's/^/prefix /; s/\0/\n/g'
prefix one
prefix two
$ printf 'one\0two\0' | perl -np -e 's/^/prefix /; s/\0/\n/g'
prefix one
two
```

You can look up the command-line options of Perl by running `perldoc perlrun`.

Comment: Can you explain the difference between `perldoc perlrun` and `man perl` please? They both look really similar.

Answer (score 1):

To match a null byte, I use this regex with Cygwin's SED:

> [^\x01-\x7F]

Comment: This is the answer to the question for sed on GNUWin32.  It actually strips out more than just nulls.  It may or may not work for you depending on what you want to match, and the implementation of sed.