# How can I find binary data in my text file?

Tags: linux, linux-mint, search, binary-files, textfiles

I have a huge log file (several GBs), but somehow there is binary data (grep is annoyed by it) in there, which of course shouldn't be.

I know how I can read the file anyway.

I don't know how I can find the bad binary data in it so I maybe can pin point where it's logged looking at the text around it?

Comment: Well actually a text file is also a binary lol. I guess you will be looking for something that deletes all alphanumeric characters from your file, only leaving the other data in the file.

Comment: @xdevs23 Yeah it is :D. But what I'm looking for is something like grep for those files to see the the normal log text around it. So I can maybe blame what is adding those binary data.

Comment: I have no idea how you are going to be able to solve that. Maybe someone else knows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just hit the exact same problem (although it's only a multi-megabyte log file). As with a lot of problems, it just takes a couple of commands together.

```
cmp /path/to/file.log <(strings /path/to/file.log)
```

`cmp` compares files and tells you *where* they differ (unlike diff, which tells you *how* they differ). `strings` returns valid text strings from binary files. `<(…)` lets you treat the output of a command as a file descriptor into another command.

Basically, you compare the log file with the text strings in the log file so that you find where they first differ.

For example, I get `A and B differ: byte 1450315, line 6390`. Running `tail -n +6390 /path/to/file.log | less` shows the log starting at the "bad" line, or you can pipe through `| hexdump -C | less` to see the hex (piping through `head -n 1` didn't work for me because the binary was `\x00` characters, which only showed when there was a pager)

(Note: This may not work well with multi-gigabyte logs if the machine does not have sufficient memory - I don't know how memory efficient `strings` and `cmp` are)

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the same problem. What worked for me, was to simply `head` the file incrementally and grep it to see at which line the binary characters occur.

At the beginning, I called `head -n 1`, there was no binary character.
Then `head -n 2`, then `head -n 3`... and so on. Soon I found the line, where the binary character were present.

Answer (score 0):

Building on @ibboard's great idea: `find-non-printable.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh
usage="$0 FILE - Locates first non-printable byte, as in 'FILE - differ: byte 21881, line 507'";
n_bytes=$(stat --printf='%s' "$1");
# -w: --include-all-whitespace
strings -w "$1" | cmp -n "$n_bytes" "$1";
```

- No output when no non-printable characters are found, instead of message like `cmp: EOF on FILE after byte 1677, line 47`.
- Simple pipe instead of using `<()`. Works with a POSIX shell instead of requiring Bash or ZSH. Output shows `-` as file name instead of `/dev/...`.
- Works as expected when the file contains blank lines. This requires a `strings` implementation that supports `-w`, such as GNU `strings`. Without this, the result just points to the first blank line, which is often not the desired result.
- User needs to type file name only once.

Answer (score 0):

If you have `my_file` that contains (in `vim`):

```
test data 1
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@test data 2
test data 3
```

`grep` is bothered by the null byte (hex value 00, represented as `^@` in `vim`). If you search for a regular string 'data' with `$ grep 'data' my_file` you get `Binary file my_file matches` which is not the expected result. If you want to examine/remove null bytes by hand, you can find the offending bytes with:

```
$ < my_file hexdump -C | grep -C2 ' 00'
00000000  74 65 73 74 20 64 61 74  61 20 31 0a 00 00 00 00  |test data 1.....|
00000010  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 74 65  |..............te|
00000020  73 74 20 64 61 74 61 20  32 0a 74 65 73 74 20 64  |st data 2.test d|
00000030  61 74 61 20 33 0a                                 |ata 3.|
```

and see the regular strings nearby the null bytes, which you can then search for in vim and edit (don't search for the periods; they represent whitespace characters like newline and null byte rather than literal `.`.)
If you want to remove them [programmatically](https://superuser.com/a/287998/941084):

```
$ < my_file sed 's/\x0//g' > my_file_without_nulls
```